# What's wrong with my attempt to write my own Array.prototype.join()?

Tags: javascript, recursion, join

I have been trying to implement a bunch of higher order functions myself. Just for the fun of it.

Today though, I found myself stuck on the attempt to reproduce the Array.join method.

I have set myself a challenge not to use any loops such as `for` or `while`, use as little `if` statements as possible and reduce the number of variables used.

Below is my attempt:

```js
Array.prototype.implode = function(glue) {
    return (function loop(arr, str) {
        return (arr.length > 1
            ? loop(arr.slice(0, 1), str + arr[0] + (glue || ''))
            : str);
    })(this, '');
};

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
console.log(arr.implode('#')); // a#
```

Comment: Could you post your error?

Comment: @Baruch There is no error. It just outputs 'a#'

Comment: `.slice(0, 1)` returns the first element; you probably want `slice(1)`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bhdj1n79/

Comment: What @ChrisG said: https://repl.it/@baruchvlz/WorrisomePiercingServers

Comment: Oh damn, How could I have missed that.. Thanks @ChrisG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should start handling the end case of a recursive function, than the other. It's easier :)

However, you should slice from the second element to the end, not only the first element.

```js
Array.prototype.implode = function (glue) {
  return (function loop(array, glue) {
    return (
      array.length === 1
      ? array[0]
      : array[0] + glue + loop(array.slice(1), glue)
    )
  })(this, glue || '')
}

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
console.log(arr.implode('#'));
// a#b#c#d#e#f
```

Comment: This is some sexy piece of code. Thanks for sharing